# Visual Studio Web development - removing code duplication

Tags: visual-studio, code-duplication

I am developing a basic .html website using visual studio.  I am wondering on how other people find this experience.  I do not really want to replicate the navigation, header, footer code in each page so what do you use?

I was thinking I might have to use master pages and aspx, unfortunately masterpages and .html do not go.  In dreamweaver there used to be templates you could use for each section, which get parsed in when you display the website.  I also know there may be various server-side workarounds but I am not really interested in that.

So, how do you cope?  Are there any visual studio plugins I should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master pages is what you want. If you're using Visual Studio, just switch to aspx pages. They're no different than HTML as far as markup is concerned, so you'll be able to move your html to them easily.

Comment: Alright, that seems to be the best way then.  I do not like how master pages pull out all the html line breaks though (perfectionist).